# Searching and Editing Values in Swift Array or Dictionary

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a method which is supposed to return a Set of Strings. Here is a method description:

- Returns: 10 product names containing the specified string.
  If there are several products with the same name, producer's name is added to product's name in the format `"<producer> - <product>`",
  otherwise returns simply `"<product>"`.

Can't figure out how to check if there are duplicate names in the array and then edit them as required

What I've got so far:

```
struct Product {
    let id: String; // unique identifier
    let name: String;
    let producer: String;
}

protocol Shop {

    func addNewProduct(product: Product) -> Bool

    func deleteProduct(id: String) -> Bool
    
    func listProductsByName(searchString: String) -> Set<String>
    
    func listProductsByProducer(searchString: String) -> [String]
}

class ShopImpl: Shop {
    
    private var goodsInTheShopDictionary: [String: Product] = [:]
        
    func addNewProduct(product: Product) -> Bool {
        let result = goodsInTheShopDictionary[product.id] == nil
        if result {
            goodsInTheShopDictionary[product.id] = product
        }
        return result
    }
    
    func deleteProduct(id: String) -> Bool {
        let result = goodsInTheShopDictionary[id] != nil
        if result {
            goodsInTheShopDictionary.removeValue(forKey: id)
        }
        return result
    }

    
    func listProductsByName(searchString: String) -> Set<String> {
        var result = Set<String>()
    
        let searchedItems = goodsInTheShopDictionary.filter{ $0.value.name.contains(searchString) }
        let resultArray = searchedItems.map{ $0.value }
        
        
        
        result = Set(searchedItems.map{ $0.value.name })
        if result.count > 10 {
            result.removeFirst()
        }

        return result
        
    }
    

}
```

Comment: Instead of mapping value.name into a Set loop over the resultArray and check if each name is in result (which can be an array or set) and either add it or add it together with producer name. Then use `prefix(10)` on that result to get the first 10 or break the loop once 10 items has been found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this you would need to iterate over you `resultArray` and save `producer` and `product` into another array. On each iteration you would need to check if the array allready contains either the product name itself or an allready modified version.

A possible implementation would look like this:

```
var result = [(producer: String, product: String)]()
// iterate over the first 10 results
for item in resultArray.prefix(10){
    if let index = result.firstIndex(where: { _ , product in
        product == item.name
    }){
        // the result array allready contains the exact product name
        // so we need to convert the name allready in the list
        let oldProduct = (producer: result[index].producer, product: "\(result[index].producer) \(result[index].product)")
        result[index] = oldProduct
        // add the new one
        result.append((producer: item.producer, product: "\(item.producer) \(item.name)"))
    }
    else if !result.filter({ $0.product.components(separatedBy: " ").contains(item.name)}).isEmpty {
        // if the result array allready contains a modified version of the name
        result.append((producer: item.producer, product: "\(item.producer) \(item.name)"))
    } else{
        // if the result array does not contain the product yet
        result.append((producer: item.producer, product: "\(item.name)"))
    }
}

let productNames = result.map{ $0.product}
```

---

Please be aware: As you are using a `[String: Product]`, which is a unsorted dictionary, to hold your values this will yield different results (if the `resultArray` collection is larger than 10) each time you search.

---

Tested with `searchString = name1`:

```
var goodsInTheShopDictionary: [String: Product] = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: (0...20).map { index in
    ("\(index)",Product(id: "", name: "name\(index)", producer: "producer\(index)"))
})

goodsInTheShopDictionary["100"] = Product(id: "11", name: "name1", producer: "producer11")
goodsInTheShopDictionary["101"] = Product(id: "12", name: "name1", producer: "producer12")
```

Result:

> ["name13", "producer12 name1", "name10", "name19", "producer11 name1",
> "name17", "name14", "name18", "producer1 name1", "name16"]